# How to bring ng-table inside tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngtable

I've trouble having to implement the ng-table inside tab. I'm using ng-include to include the template into tab which contains ng-table attrubutes. When changing tab to tab ng-table not working?

When changing tab i'm passing the tab content item number two switch b/w two tab.

```
$scope.changeTab = function(tabItem)
{
    switch(tabItem)
    {

      case "1":
                     data = $resource("/data/tab1.json");
                     $scope.table1 = new ngTableParams({ .. });
                  break;
     case "2":
                     data = $resource("/data/tab2.json");
                     $scope.table2 = new ngTableParams({ .. });
                  break;
     default: break
    }
}
    $scope.changeTab(1);
```

When i'm runnign first time the table works fine. When switching b/w tab table not generating.

Any suggestion or solution to get rid of this problem?

Comment: It'd be really helpful if you could include a plnkr or fiddle, to show the not-working part in action.

Comment: `not working` is a pretty poor description. We're not here to play 20 questions....detailed questions get help fast, others just get ignored